# How to "group a tbl" in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to get bootstrap samples of rows in a dataframe, by level of factor. For that, I'm using `ddply` and `sample_n`. However, I need to set a `size` argument for `sample_n`, as this returns an error message:

```
ddply (mtcars, .(carb), .fun = sample_n, replace=TRUE)
```

In `?sample` I read for the `size` argument that *if tbl is **grouped**, size applies to each group*. I think this is what I'm looking for, but I cannot find any additional info on how I should group the `tbl` argument. Isn't grouped yet inside the `ddply` function?

Please note that I don't want to run the function above for a fixed number of rows (ej:  `ddply (mtcars, .(carb), .fun = sample_n, size = 2, replace=TRUE))`, as it could vary depending on the level of the factor. In this example, I would expect 10 samples for the carb=2 level, 3 for carb=3, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `purrr`. In the following code, we split the data frame by `carb` using `split(.$carb)`. `map2_df` can apply a function through each element in a list (`.x`, Here is a list of splitted data frame) and a vector or list (`.y`), and then return a combined data frame. `.y = c(3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1)` specifies the sampling number per group.

```
set.seed(123)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  split(.$carb) %>%
  map2_df(.y = c(3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1), ~.x %>% sample_n(size = .y, replace = TRUE))

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
2  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
3  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
4  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
5  21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
6  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
7  17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
8  13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
9  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
10 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
11 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
12 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: Is there a way to get as many samples by "group" as observations in that group?

Comment: @EuGENE Please see my updates. I think I found a way.

Comment: why not use `map_df(~.x %>% sample_n(size = nrow(.x), replace = TRUE))` instead of map2_df()` to get samples to match number of observations in a group?

Comment: @NateDay Thanks for sharing this nice solution. In the original post, OP states that `10 samples for the carb=2 level, 3 for carb=3`, so I assume that OP may want to define sample size to each group. I think this is why I proposed the `map2_df` solution. However, if the OP wants the sample size to be exactly the same as the row numbers, and then your solution will be better because the OP does not need to specify the sample size again.

Comment: ahha I missed the stipulations on the size per group in the quesiton... I was just reading the comments down here.